# Needs to Implement Java Mail with no-reply@domain.com

Tags: java, spring-boot, jakarta-mail

I implemented Java Mail service by using Gmail Server. It is working fine. But I want to send an email with no-rely@domain.com

I implemented Java mail service by using Spring-Boot starter mail. In application properties, I have set the authentication and server port. After that, I have implemented Email service and send the used JavaMailSender.

```
Application.yml

 mail:
    host: smtp.gmail.com
    port: 587
    username: 
    password: 
    properties:
      mail:
        smtp:
          auth: true
          starttls:
            enable: true  

MailService:

public class EmailServiceImpl implements EmailService {

    @Autowired
    private JavaMailSender mailSender;

    /**
     * Send email.
     *
     * @param to the to
     * @param subject the subject
     * @param text the text
     */
    @Override
    public void sendEmail(String to, String subject, String text) {

        try {
            SimpleMailMessage message = new SimpleMailMessage();
            message.setTo(to);
            message.setSubject(subject);
            message.setText(text);

            mailSender.send(message);
        } catch (MailException e) {
            log.info("Mail Exception {}", e);
        }


    }
```

I have 2 Questions.

Q1. How can I implement without the Authorization? I just want to send an email to the user so that he knows about status.

Q2. I want to send an email from "no-reply@domain.com". So no one reply to this email.

Answer (score 0):

A1. You can't.  If you could, every spammer would use it.

A2. You can't.  If you could, every spammer would use it.

You have to authenticate, and Gmail will only let you use a "From" address that corresponds to your account, unless you use the non-free service.

Comment: In many cases, we saw an email coming from "no-reply@domain.com" than how it is possible.

Comment: @VimitDhawan: if you set up your own mail server you can do it also